# Preferred way of creating shared pointers

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) states that `std::make_shared<T>` typically allocates memory for `T` and the smart pointer's control block at once in contrast to `std::shared_pointer<T>(new T)`, which performs two allocations. Does it mean it is more efficient and therefore a one should always use `std::make_shared` if possible?

The same question about Qt equivalent - `QSharedPointer`. According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#create) the `QSharedPointer` internals and the object are allocated in one single memory allocation, which could help reduce memory fragmentation in a long-running application. Does it mean `QSharedPointer<T>::create()` is the preferred one?

```cpp
class MyClass {};

QSharedPointer<MyClass> ptr1 = QSharedPointer<MyClass>::create();   // better
QSharedPointer<MyClass> ptr2(new MyClass);  // worse
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::make_shared` is preferred in almost every case.  However, if you use weak pointers, you can easily get into a "memory leak" situation where memory is kept around far longer than you would think at first glance (after all `shared_ptr`s are gone).

As long as there is a `std::weak_ptr` associated with a `std::shared_ptr` control block, the control block must remain.  Since `std::make_shared` creates a single memory allocation for both the control block and the data, if the control block remains, the data must remain, too.  With `std::shared_ptr`, the there are two allocations, so they can be cleaned up independently.

So, if you're not using `std::weak_ptr` (additional caveats below), absolutely always prefer `std::make_shared` for benefits including the number of allocations and exception safety.  If you are using `std::weak_ptr`, you must be much more thoughtful about your design.

*Modern Effective C++* chapter 4 is dedicated to how/when to use different smart pointers.  It's a concise book for existing c++ programmers to catch up on the new features in c++11/14, including smart pointers.

edit: as @midor mentions, you there is also simply no option to provide a custom deleter when using `std::make_shared`.  Also, if the type T has different constructors that could be called with the same type but one with `()` and one with `{}`, then it will always prefer the one with `()`.  For example `std::make_shared<std::vector>(10,10)` calls `std::vector(10,10)` not `std::vector{10,10}`.

Comment: What are the benefits of `std::make_shared` regarding exception safety?

Comment: Since you refer to the book don't forget to mention the other case where it is not an option: when specifying custom deleters

Comment: Probably worth clarifying that it is not really a "memory leak", but rather just a situation when a larger memory chunk gets "held" by weak pointers. Memory just gets deallocated later (or much later) than it could have been in case of a shared pointer created with an explicit `new`.

Comment: @Dadam It's very easy to write code where an exception thrown on the same line can cause memory to be allocated, but never make it in to the shared_ptr constructor to be stored for later deletion: f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g()) if g() throws, new int(42) could have already run.

Comment: @AnT I think between putting it in quotes and later going into the exact details of why the memory would be kept around, it both gives a clear high-level view of the problem as well as the details on how to avoid it.  I changed the first paragraph a little, though, anyhow.

Comment: You're making very specific comments about implementations of the standard library. You need to reference specific library implementation versions, and ideally give links to code. The standard doesn't force the control block to remain solely on the account of weak pointers being present. There are simple lock-free ways of iterating a linked list of weak pointers and detaching them from the control block, allowing the control block to be freed. I'm not claiming that any particular implementation acts that way, but it definitely could, with deallocation cost O(N) in the number of weak pointers.

Comment: @KubaOber sometimes being technically correct is worse.  But now your comment is there for someone to read if they are concerned about it.